# How to check if there is a comment or not

Tags: python, excel, com, comments

I've got an .xlsx file. Some cells in it have comments which content will be used thereafter. How to check, iterating through every cell, if it has a comment or not?
This code (in which I tried to iterate the third column and nothing else) returns an error:

```
import win32com.client, win32gui, re
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = 1
TempExchFilePath = win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW()[0]
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(TempExchFilePath)
sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
comments = None
for i in range (0,201,1):
   if sh.Cells(2,i).Comment.Text() != None:
      comment = sh.Cells(2,i).Comment.Text()
      comments += comment
print(comments)
input()
```

I am very new to Python and sorry for my English.
Thanks! :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I think is the best way, using the [Python Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) modules, specifically `xlrd`

Suppose you have a workbook which has a cell A1 with a comment written by Joe Schmo which says "Hi!", here's how you'd get at that.

```
>>> from xlrd import *
>>> wb = open_workbook("test.xls")
>>> sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
>>> notes = sheet.cell_note_map
>>> print notes
{(0, 0): <xlrd.sheet.Note object at 0x00000000033FE9E8>}
>>> notes[0,0].text
u'Schmo, Joe:\nHi!'
```

**A Quick Explanation of What's Going On**

So the `xlrd` module is a pretty handy thing, once you figure it out (full documentation [here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966)).  The first two lines import the module and create a workbook object called `wb`.  Next, we create a sheet object of the first sheet (index 0) and call that `sheet` (I'm feeling creative today).  Then we create a dicitonary of note objects called `notes` with the `cell_note_map` attribute of our sheet object.  This dictionary has the (row,col) index of the comment as the key, and then a note object as the value.  We can then extract the text of that note using the `text` attribute of the note object.

For multiple notes, you can iterate through your dictionary to get at all the text as show below:

```
>>> comments = []
>>> for key in notes.keys():
...     comments.append(notes[key].text)
...
>>> print comments
[u"Schmo, Joe:\nHere's another\n", u'Schmo, Joe:\nhi!']
```

**Some Things to Note**

- This will only work with `.xls` files, not `.xlsx`, but you can save any `.xlsx` as an `.xls` so there's no problem
- The author of the comment will always be listed first, but can be accessed separately by using the `author` attribute instead of `text`.  There will also always be a `\n` inbetween the author and text.
- Cells which do not have comments will not be mapped by `cell_note_map`.  So a full sheet without any comments will yield an empty dictionary

Comment: Seems to be the most powerful way to solve the problem, thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think defining comments as `None` and then trying to add Stuff (i guess a string) won't work.

Try `comments = ""` instead of `comments = None`

Other then that, it would deffinitly help to see the error.

Comment: Thank you!
So, this is the text of an error after I changed None into "" as you adviced:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/Google Диск/python/stacktry.py", line 9, in <module>
    if sh.Cells(2,i).Comment.Text() != None:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 192, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)


P. S. "Ошибка" = "Error"

Comment: did you change the None in line 9 or 7? because i meant the None in line 7 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. However, you have

```
comments = None
```

and then

```
comments += comment
```

I don't think you can do `None` + anything. Most likely, you either want to do

```
comments = ''
comments += comment
```

or

```
comments = []
comments.append(comment)
```

Another thing you probably need to fix:

```
if sh.Cells(2,i).Comment.Text() != None:
```

The `(2,i)` syntax doesn't appear to work in python. Change to `Cells[2][i]`. Also, if `Comment` doesn't exist, then it will be `None` , and won't have a `Text()` function. i.e.:

```
if sh.Cells[2][i].Comment != None:
    comment = sh.Cells[2][i].Comment.Text()
```

Comment: It didn't help the problem (shows an error I written above), but thank you anyway!